# Suppress automatic colorbar with plt.contourf()

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, colorbar

I'm wondering how to suppress the automatic colorbar which is generated when data in an xarray DataArray is plotted using the plot.contourf() method. If possible, I would like to either (a) set the cbar_visible to False (so that `old cbar` is not generated) or (b) access that cbar object to modify as with `new cbar`.

```
data = xr.DataArray(state.rand(20,20))

plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

im = data.plot.contourf(x='dim_0', y='dim_1', cbar_kwargs={'label':'old cbar'})
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, label='new cbar')
```

[image: Output from code block]

Comment: [xarray's contourf](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.plot.contourf.html)  has a parameter `data.plot.contourf(...., add_colorbar=False)`.

Comment: That solves my issue - thank you!